# Place a non editable percentage sign within a HTML input field

Tags: html, css

I currently have a series of input field boxes which are numerical based. The trouble I am having is adding a '%' symbol at the end of each box. Ultimately i want the % symbol to be non editable to the user however unsure how to go about it. Any ideas would be beneficial

HTML

```
<div class="ModifiedValues">
    <span class="valuePadding"><center><b>New Value</b></center></span>
    <span class="valuePadding"><input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputRRPDiscount" style="text-align:left;"><br></span>
    <span class="valuePadding"><input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputMargin" style="text-align:left;"><br></span>
    <span class="valuePadding"><input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputMarkUp" style="text-align:left;"><br></span>
    <span class="valuePadding"><input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputSalesDiscount" style="text-align:left;"><br></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ModifiedValues { 
        position: absolute;
        left: 250px;
        top: 28px;
        color: #666;
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 85px;
}   

.valuePadding { 
        padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
        display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Here you go

```css
.valuePadding {
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
}
.valuePadding input {
  border: none;
  padding:0px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="valuePadding"><input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputRRPDiscount" style="text-align:left;">%</span>
<br>
```

Comment: Good answers include explanation, not just code.

Answer (score 7):

I would style your spans to look like your inputs and then remove the styles from the input.  You can then use the `after` psuedo selector to add the percentage:

```css
.input-holder {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.input-holder > input {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline:none;
}
.input-holder:after {
  content: '%';
}
```

```html
<div class="ModifiedValues">
  <span class="valuePadding"><center><b>New Value</b></center></span>
  <span class="valuePadding input-holder"><input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputRRPDiscount" style="text-align:left;"></span>
  <br>
  <span class="valuePadding input-holder"><input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputMargin" style="text-align:left;"></span>
  <br>
  <span class="valuePadding input-holder"><input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputMarkUp" style="text-align:left;"></span>
  <br>
  <span class="valuePadding input-holder"><input type="number" max="100" accuracy="2" min="0" id="inputSalesDiscount" style="text-align:left;"></span>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're going to put these elements within a relative positioned div, you could handle it this way:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <span id="percent-sign">%</span>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="100">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    #percent-sign {
        top: 8px;
        left: 45px;
        color: #555;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
```

Notice that I'm using Bootstrap grid classes (col-md-6), **which already gave that div relative positioning**. If that's not your case, set relative positioning to your div.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, Unfortunately i coudlnt come up with a decent way to do it without js thatw asnt too annoying but.. this is what I ended up using: feel free to copy and paste js into a file, and any TEXT input with id "PercentageInput" should be formatted accordingly.

it might be important to note, depending on how you do things you may need to implement a function to remove none numerical characters from the value before parsing it

hope it helps someone

```js
document.getElementById("PercentageInput").addEventListener("input", function (event) {
    formatPercentage(this, event);
});

// Function to format a percentage input
function formatPercentage(input, event) {
    // Remove non-numeric characters from the input value
    let value = input.value.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');

    // Check if backspace key is pressed
    if (event.inputType === 'deleteContentBackward') {
        // Check if the first digit is being deleted
        if (value.length === 1) {
            // Set the value to 0.00% if the first digit is deleted
            input.value = '0.00%';
            return;
        }

        // Delete the last digit
        value = value.slice(0, -1);
    }

    // Check if the input is empty
    if (value === '') {
        // Display 0.00% when the input is empty
        input.value = '0.00%';
        return;
    }

    // Remove leading zeros from the input value
    value = value.replace(/^0+/, '');

    // Separate the whole part and decimal part of the value
    const wholePart = value.slice(0, -2);
    const decimalPart = value.slice(-2);

    // Add commas to the whole part for better readability
    let formattedValue = wholePart.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    
    // Combine the whole and decimal parts with a period and add a percent symbol
    formattedValue += `.${decimalPart}%`;

    // Set the formatted value back to the input
    input.value = formattedValue;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #283238;
}
.infoBox {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 6px outset darkgrey;
  color: darkergrey;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

label, input {
  width: 90%;
  margin:6px;
  border: 1px inset grey;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="infoBox" id="ValueA">
    <label for="PercentageInput">Input a Percentage</p>
    <input type="text" id="PercentageInput" placeholder="100.00%">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

I just made the custom percent input element.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Input Percent</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
</head>  
<body>
  <div class="percent_input" id="red_liquid_percent">

     <div class="button_group">
          <i id="up_button" class="fas fa-sort-up"></i>
          <i id="down_button" class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
      </div>
     <p id="percent_value">0%</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check [JSFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/cristianr909090/m6kdv03j/) here.