# number not displaying as percentage in angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to display the number in percentage format in my angular UI. At the moment it is rendering the actual value. So if it 2 percent , it is showing 0.02. I need to display it as 2 percent

```
<click-input contenteditable="true" *ngIf="item.fieldInfo.dataCategory == fieldCategories.percent" [classNames]="['percentage']">
    <input [(ngModel)]="item.value" name="item.fieldInfo.key"   required min="0" max="999999999999999"/>
</click-input>
```

css

```
table {
    tbody {
        td {
            div.percentage {
                    padding:0.5rem;
                    &:after {
                        content: '%';
                    }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built-in [angular percent pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe) instead

In your non-editable-content code use it like so:

```
<div>{{item.value | percent}}</div>
```

Comment: Would appreciate the reason for the downvote, would help me answer questions better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify type of your input tag as number, then you can do something like that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40885513/3602220