# css - display percent sign after value inside input

Tags: css

I need to add a percent sign after the numeric value of an input element. Should look something like this:

[image]

I thought that I can solve this by using ::after

```
<input type="text" class="percent">

.percent::after {
    content: ' %';
}
```

but it looks like this is not the correct way to do it.
The percent sigh should stick with the value, this means it should move when digits are added into the input.
To add the % to the value of the input when the user types is not an acceptable solution.
Any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: _"The percent sigh should stick with the value"_ - that's gonna be tricky, because if you wanted to position it absolutely, you will need to measure how wide the text inside the input field actually runs. Maybe a span with contenteditable set could be an alternative - that would automatically be as wide, as its content requires, so the % could simply "follow" next in normal flow. (You'd have to take the text content of the span and put it into a hidden field then, if you wanted to submit the value together with the rest of a form.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place a non editable percentage sign within a HTML input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885376/place-a-non-editable-percentage-sign-within-a-html-input-field)

Comment: @prettyInPink: the solutions in your link are not good for my case - the % is fixed, and I need to stick to the value.

Comment: @CBroe: I couldn't find the reason why ::after content is not working. Any explanation for this?

Comment: https://webplatform.news/issues/2020-08-26 - generated pseudo content using ::before/::after is supposed to behave the same, as if a new child element was inserted into the element you apply them to. Input fields can not have child elements.

Comment: Does it have to be an input? Or can it be a div or other with ```contenteditable```?

Comment: must be an input element. at least I try first to find the solution for input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by using `contenteditable` element instead of `input`, not sure if this is a possibility?

```css
.percent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.percent::after {
  content: '%';
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.percentVal {
  flex: 1;
}

.wrapper input {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="percent" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="with_percent" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">
  <div class="percentVal">%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yah, this should be a possible fix. But at this moment I'm looking for a solution when using "input" tag.

Comment: Added another try :)

Comment: this looks much better. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

you could instead use javascript to change the input value to include a percent sign

```js
let ipt = document.querySelector("#n_percent");
function toPercent() {

  ipt.value = ipt.value + " %"
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n_percent" onfocusout="toPercent()">
```